# Data carrying intent vs pulling data after login

Tags: android, android-intent, server

I am making an android application and I got stuck at some point. In the login process, I have two options but I do not know which is safer.

1. Carry data with intent via putExtra method
2. Just carry id by intent and then pull data from server with known id.

Can you help me figure out which one to be applied?

Comment: It's depends . If you carry data with intent then you will show the data which was loaded recently . And with id each time latest data will be loaded . So you need to figure out the weather the data can be changed or not for logged in user .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can do both ways

1) Carry data with intent via putExtra method

Ans 1 :
If you are showing only intent data on the passing activity then it is fine

Ans 2 :
You can use SharedPreferences to store the data in login page and then you can access that data in passing activity/fragment.(just make sure to clear the SharedPreferences after logout)

2) Just carry id by intent and then pull data from server with known id.

Ans : This is fine also you can just call the api like getProfile and get the data from api. You can show the updated data every time you call the api,which is good.

Comment: I am using sharedpreferences for the login page not to see login page again and again in the same device. for what purpose I can use shared preferences in app except for login page?  I already give the data with intent if I choose the first option. I am confused.

Comment: You can use this library for easy data sharing: https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator